# Why can't I evaluate this bivariate definite integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, regions

I want to directly use the x function to find the exact value of the following bivariate definite integral:

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 1 && x >= 0, {x, y}];
(* the answer should be π/2*Log[2] *)
Integrate[(1 + x*y)/(1 + x^2 + y^2), Element[{x, y}, reg]]
```

This bivariate integral is not complicated, but the above formula returns as it is. I want to know where the problem is and how I should modify it.

```
NIntegrate[(1 + x*y)/(1 + x^2 + y^2), Element[{x, y}, reg]]
(*1.08879304515*)
```

Comment: This is worth reporting to Support.

Comment: Despite your words, this is not a simple integral in the cartesian coordinates: both `Integrate[(1 + x*y)/(1 + x^2 + y^2), {x, 0, 1}, {y, -Sqrt[1 - x^2], 
  Sqrt[1 - x^2]}]` and `Integrate[(1 + x*y)/(1 + x^2 + y^2), {y, -1, 1}, {x, 0, 
  Sqrt[1 - y^2]}]` fail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Integrate[(1 + x*y)/(1 + x^2 + y^2), {x, y} ∈ Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {-π/2, π/2}]]
```

Comment: Ah, I forgot that you can use `Disk[]` to make sectors.

Answer (score 7):

One could just use an alternative region specification:

```
reg = RegionIntersection[Disk[], HalfPlane[{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}]];
Integrate[(1 + x y)/(1 + x^2 + y^2), {x, y} ∈ reg]
   1/2 π Log[2]
```

or switch to polar coordinates:

```
Simplify[((1 + x y)/(1 + x^2 + y^2) /. Thread[{x, y} -> r AngleVector[θ]])
         Det[D[r AngleVector[θ], {{r, θ}}]]]
   (r + r^3 Cos[θ] Sin[θ])/(1 + r^2)

Integrate[(r + r^3 Cos[θ] Sin[θ])/(1 + r^2), {r, 0, 1}, {θ, -π/2, π/2}]
   1/2 π Log[2]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I want to know why we can't solve this problem directly. If you can, you can tag this post with `bugs` to attract professional attention.

Comment: @Monte, it's more of a "missing feature" than a bug. As you are already aware, *Mathematica* echoes the input if it doesn't know what to do with it, which is the case here.